# Column top offset in css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I need some help with my css code.
I'm using css grid.
I have 2 columns.
How to add a top offset for the right column?
That is result that I want to get:

[image: img]

```css
.parent {
  background-color:#ddd;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.child {
  background-color:#aaa;
  padding:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum provident adipisci, voluptates aliquam corporis magnam. Dolor aliquam reprehenderit molestiae in quam quae adipisci vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum provident adipisci, voluptates aliquam corporis magnam. Dolor aliquam reprehenderit molestiae in quam quae adipisci vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum provident adipisci, </p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum provident adipisci, voluptates aliquam corporis magnam. Dolor aliquam reprehenderit molestiae in quam quae adipisci vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus? in quam quae adipisci vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus? in quam quae adipisci vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum provident adipisci, voluptates aliquam corporis magnam. Dolor aliquam reprehenderit molestiae in quam quae adipisci vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum provident adipisci, voluptates aliquam corporis magnam. Dolor aliquam reprehenderit molestiae in quam quae adipisci vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is just a dummy text because stackoverflow thinks there is not enough details for submit my question.

Comment: There are several ways to create the offset. Relative positioning, as suggested below, is one method. There's also a pure CSS Grid solution. I didn't post it because it's more complex than the positioning answer provided. But if that doesn't work for you, let me know and I'll post an alternative.

Comment: I think that is interesting for all of users to see pure CSS Grid solution! )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `top: 20px` for the even child element. (Remember to set `position: relative` to child element)

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.child {
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 15px;
}

.child:nth-of-type(even) {
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum provident adipisci, voluptates aliquam corporis magnam. Dolor aliquam reprehenderit molestiae in quam quae adipisci vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum provident adipisci, voluptates aliquam corporis magnam. Dolor aliquam reprehenderit molestiae in quam quae adipisci vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum provident adipisci, </p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum provident adipisci, voluptates aliquam corporis magnam. Dolor aliquam reprehenderit molestiae in quam quae adipisci vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus? in quam quae adipisci
      vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus? in quam quae adipisci vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum provident adipisci, voluptates aliquam corporis magnam. Dolor aliquam reprehenderit molestiae in quam quae adipisci vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum provident adipisci, voluptates aliquam corporis magnam. Dolor aliquam reprehenderit molestiae in quam quae adipisci vel culpa quibusdam, iure expedita nam doloribus?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```